# Brain teaser involving fingers

Tags: pattern

[image]

I was given this brain teaser in my math class as just a fun problem that we could try for extra credit. However, everyone in my class is completely lost. Here’s the information I could get from the problem: 1=5, 2=2, 3=2, 4=3, 5=2, 6=1, 7=4, 8=?

P.S. excuse the extra writing or the black line in the middle of the picture.

Comment: Hello! Glad to have you here, do you know the answer to this? Because if not then answers will be wide and varied and may not be of any use to you.

Comment: Thanks R.D.! Unfortunately, I am not aware of what the answer to this problem is. I posted it on this site so that there may be a chance that someone out there can solve this problem. So far, none of my friends have been able to solve it, and I certainly have no leads as to what the correct answer could be.

Comment: Hmm I see. As I said, if your friends had different answers then chances are so will the people here too. I suggest you ask your professor for the answer to keep in hand. Just in case! Have fun!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> A closed fist

Reasoning is

> If you depict the number represented by the fingers on the left side on a 7 segment display, the number represented by the fingers on the right side is the number of segments remaining unlit. 8 leaves no segments unlit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don’t know how you were able to come up with an answer like that, but that’s certainly correct! You’ve done me and all my friends a favor.